# Is the langauge of (descriptions of) DFAs that accept $\Sigma^*$ decidable?

Tags: computability, automata

Is $L = \{\langle A\rangle\mid A\text{ is a DFA and }L(A) = \Sigma^*\}$ decidable?

I know that $L'=\{\langle A,w\rangle \mid A\text{ is a DFA and }w\in L(A)\}$ is decidable, but I'm not sure if this is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's decidable. Think about what an DFA's accepting states must look like if it accepts every possible string. That property is very easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Every accessible state $s$

- must be accepted
- must have a successor state $\tau (s, \sigma)$ for $\sigma \in
     \Sigma$, where $\tau$ is the transition function of the DFA.

You can check this by breadth-first (or depth-first or whatever) search from the initial state. The search terminates since the automaton is finite.